# Getting the connected components in a graph

Tags: python, graph-theory, depth-first-search, connected-components

I am trying to get all the connected components in a graph and print them out. I am going through each node of the graph and performing a depth-first-search(DFS) starting from that node. Here is my code:

```
graph = {
'a': ['b'],
'b': ['c'],
'c': ['d'],
'd': [],
'e': ['f'],
'f': []
}

def DFS(graph, start_node, stack = [], visited = []):
    stack.append(start_node)

    while stack:
        v = stack.pop()
        if v not in visited:
            visited.append(v)
            for neighbor in graph[v]:
                stack.append(neighbor)
    return visited



def dfs_get_connected_components_util(graph):
    visited = []

    for node in graph:
        if node not in visited:
            DFS_algo = DFS(graph, node)
            print(DFS_algo)
            visited = DFS_algo

print(dfs_get_connected_components_util(graph))
```

According to my graph, there are two connected components, a -> b -> c -> d
and e -> f

Instead I get the following print out:

```
['c', 'd']
['c', 'd', 'a', 'b']
['c', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'f']
['c', 'd', 'a', 'b', 'f', 'e']
```

I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong in my connected components function. I guess this may be more of a python question.

Comment: I think this relates to the issue of [mutable default arguments](https://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2012/02/15/mutable-default-arguments/)

Comment: That's only one issue... but also this problem isn't defined well. If you start walking the graph from 'c', you'll never find 'a' as a connected node. So you should define exactly what you are asking.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument)

Comment: Undirected graphs have connected components. Directed graphs have strongly connected components. Both are equivalence relations. I believe your definitions are wrong, but this is unrelated to the python specific coding issue, which has been answered.

Comment: Thanks @KennyOstrom. I have added a clarification about that. I assumed the graph is *undirected*. My solution doesn't find strongly connected components and isn't valid if the graph is directed.

Comment: That makes sense, but if the graph is undirected, your adjacency list should show both halves of each edge. {'a': ['b'], 'b': ['a']}. Just be sure to insert both when you add an edge.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I've come up with.
I added some comments inline to explain what I did.
Some stuff were moved to be global, just for clarity. I wouldn't usually recommend using global variable.

The key is to understand the recursion, and also remember that when doing assignment of an object (that's not a literal), you only assign the reference and **not** a copy of it.

Please note that this solution assumed the graph is **undirected**. See more details why at the notes section below.

Feel free to ask for clarifications.

```
from collections import defaultdict

graph = {
    'a': ['b'],
    'b': ['c'],
    'c': ['d'],
    'd': [],
    'e': ['f'],
    'f': []
}

connected_components = defaultdict(set)


def dfs(node):
    """
    The key is understanding the recursion
    The recursive assumption is:
        After calling `dfs(node)`, the `connected_components` dict contains all the connected as keys,
        and the values are *the same set* that contains all the connected nodes.
    """
    global connected_components, graph
    if node not in connected_components:
        # this is important, so neighbors won't try to traverse current node
        connected_components[node] = set()
        for next_ in graph[node]:
            dfs(next_)
            # according the recursive assumption, connected_component of `next_` is also the one of `node`
            connected_components[node] = connected_components[next_]

        # all that's left is add the current node
        connected_components[node].add(node)

for node_ in graph:
    dfs(node_)


# get all connected components and convert to tuples, so they are hashable
connected_comp_as_tuples = map(tuple, connected_components.values())

# use ``set`` to make the list of connected components distinct (without repetition)
unique_components = set(connected_comp_as_tuples)
print(unique_components)
```

### Notes

- This wasn't thoroughly tested of course... you should try with different graphs (with loops, single node components etc.)
- The code could probably be improved (in terms of performance and maybe clarity). For instance, we create a `set` for every node, even if we don't really need one (when the node has neighbors, the set is redundant and will be overwritten).
- In the original code of the OP he used [mutable default arguments](https://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2012/02/15/mutable-default-arguments/). That's a big NO NO (unless you really REALLY know what you are doing) and, as commented above, might have caused the issues. But not this time...
- Considering @kenny-ostroms comment on the question, a word on definition (which isn't related to Python): **connected components** is related to undirected graphs only. For directed graphs, the term is **strongly connected components**. The notion is the same - for each 2 nodes in such a component (directed or undirected), there's a path between these 2 nodes. So even if node 'b' is reachable from 'a', if 'a' isn't reachable from 'b' (which could happen in directed graphs only), 'a' and 'b' will not share a connected component. My solution **is not valid** for a directed graph. The solution assumes the graph can be treated as **undirected** (in other words, if 'b' is 'a's neighbor, we assume that 'a' is 'b's neighbor).